# Solving a rotating combination lock puzzle

Tags: combinatorics, searching, puzzle

The following puzzle appears in *The House of da Vinci II* and I thought it might be interesting to tackle in *Mathematica*:

[image: combination lock]

There are numbers marked on four rotating cylinders. These numbers must add up to the Roman numerals on the plate. I want an efficient way to solve these sorts of puzzles and I had a look at using [`ResourceFunction["BacktrackSearch"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/BacktrackSearch) but to make that work I'd need to list all rotations.

The puzzle requires the sums to appear in the right order (allowing looping around). There should be some values `rotations = {r1,r2,r3,r4}` that rotate each cylinder into the correct position.

```
cylinders = {
  {4, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1},
  {3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1},
  {1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 3},
  {3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1}
};

sums = FromRomanNumeral[{"XI", "V", "X", "IV", "IX", "VI"}];
```

I can solve this by brute force:

```
test[rotations_] := 
 Total[MapThread[RotateRight[#1, #2] &, {cylinders, rotations}]] == sums

Select[Tuples[Range[0, 5], {4}], test]
(* {{0, 2, 3, 4}} *)
```

Is there a more efficient method that doesn't involving filtering from a big list of tuples? I'm aware that for this particular instance it's fast, but this technique does not scale well to larger problems.

Comment: I would search for configurations that add to IV as these are the most restrictive.  (Must be 1,1,1,1, thus given just two alternatives for rings $3$ and $4$.)  Next I'd ensure the sum of VI as these are the next-most restrictive, which involves only two rings, etc.  This will cut down the search immensely.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd implement backtracking like this:

```
cylinders = {{4, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 3}, {3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1}};
sums = FromRomanNumeral[{"XI", "V", "X", "IV", "IX", "VI"}];

bt[rotations_] := If[
  Length[rotations] == 4,
  If[evaluate[rotations] == sums, Throw[rotations]],
  If[
   ! impossible[rotations],
   bt[Append[rotations, #]] & /@ Range[0, 5]
   ]
  ]

evaluate[rotations_, l_ : All] := Total@MapThread[
   RotateRight,
   {Take[cylinders, l], rotations}
   ]

impossible[rotations_] := AnyTrue[
  sums - evaluate[rotations, Length[rotations]],
  # < 0 &
  ]

bt[{0}] // Catch
```

> `{0, 2, 3, 4}`

The more ways you can come up with to exclude series of rotations that you know cannot occur, the better it will perform. In this case I used `sums - evaluate[rotations, Length[rotations]]` to rule out solutions. However, it is possible to restrict the solutions even more by using `sums - evaluate[rotations, Length[rotations]] - (4 - Length[rotations])` because the smallest value a cylinder can have is 1.

Comment: Great! The `Select` version takes 1296 tests, this one takes just 73 evaluations  + 20 calls to `impossible` which is pretty good.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another approach. Use Solve to find the 129 solutions without considerations for the order of elements in a cylinder. Then, check these solutions and keep the one consistent with rotation of the given order.

````
Clear[a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, c1, c2, c3, c4, 
  c5, c6, d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6];

cylinders = {{4, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 
    3}, {3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1}};
sums = FromRomanNumeral[{"XI", "V", "X", "IV", "IX", "VI"}];

(* function takes two lists and returns True if equivalent by \
rotation *)
isRotation[cyl_List, sol_List] := (
  double = Flatten[Append[cyl, cyl]];
  seq = SequenceCases[double, sol];
  If[seq == {}, False, True]
  )

(* To name variables to solve for,the four cylinders are assigned a \
letter a to d. Each of the six values for a cylinder is assigned a \
number from 1 to 6. This gives 129 solutions. *)

mySolution = 
  Solve[a1 + b1 + c1 + d1 == sums[[1]] &&
    
    a2 + b2 + c2 + d2 == sums[[2]] &&
    
    a3 + b3 + c3 + d3 == sums[[3]] &&
    
    a4 + b4 + c4 + d4 == sums[[4]] &&
    
    a5 + b5 + c5 + d5 == sums[[5]] &&
    
    a6 + b6 + c6 + d6 == sums[[6]] &&
    
    a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + a5 + a6 == Total[cylinders[[1]]] &&
    
    b1 + b2 + b3 + b4 + b5 + b6 == Total[cylinders[[2]]] &&
    
    c1 + c2 + c3 + c4 + c5 + c6 == Total[cylinders[[3]]] &&
    
    d1 + d2 + d3 + d4 + d5 + d6 == Total[cylinders[[4]]] &&
    
    5 > a1 > 0 && 5 > a2 > 0 && 5 > a3 > 0 && 5 > a4 > 0 && 
    5 > a5 > 0 && 5 > a6 > 0 &&
    5 > b1 > 0 && 5 > b2 > 0 && 
    5 > b3 > 0 && 5 > b4 > 0 && 5 > b5 > 0 && 5 > b6 > 0 &&
    
    5 > c1 > 0 && 5 > c2 > 0 && 5 > c3 > 0 && 5 > c4 > 0 && 
    5 > c5 > 0 && 5 > c6 > 0 &&
    5 > d1 > 0 && 5 > d2 > 0 && 
    5 > d3 > 0 && 5 > d4 > 0 && 5 > d5 > 0 && 5 > d6 > 0 &&
    
    a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 == Times @@ cylinders[[1]] &&
    
    b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6 == Times @@ cylinders[[2]] &&
    
    c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 == Times @@ cylinders[[3]] &&
    
    d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 d6 == Times @@ cylinders[[4]],
   
   {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, c1, c2, c3, c4, 
    c5, c6, d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6}, Integers
   ];

(* Go through the solutions and select the one consistent with \
cylinder rotation *)
n = 1;
While[n <= Length[mySolution],
 truthValues = {};
 v = Values[mySolution[[n]]];
 parts = Partition[v, 6];
 i = 1;
 While[i <= Length[parts],
  truthValues = 
   Append[truthValues, isRotation[cylinders[[i]], parts[[i]]]];
  i++;
  ];
 If[truthValues == {True, True, True, True},
  Print[Column[Partition[Values[mySolution[[n]]], 6]]]
  ];
 
 n++;
 ]


(* ==== SOLUTION ==== *)
{4,1,1,1,3,1}
{2,1,3,1,1,1}
{4,1,3,1,2,2}
{1,2,3,1,3,2}```
````

Answer (score 2):

Using the comment by Mr. David G. Stork as a guide:

```
cylinders = {{4, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 
    3}, {3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1}};
sums = FromRomanNumeral[{"XI", "V", "X", "IV", "IX", "VI"}]
```

> {11, 5, 10, 4, 9, 6}

Consider the integer partitions of the entries in the `sums`.

```
iparts = IntegerPartitions[#, {4}, Range @@ MinMax[cylinders]] & /@ 
   sums // Grid
```

[image]

---

All rotated positions:

```
combs = Table[RotateRight[#, i], {i, 0, Length@# - 1}] & /@ cylinders
```

The filtered possibilities can be computed where the fourth position is always all `1s` and the second position can have `1s` or `2s`:

```
t = (combs // DeleteCases[#, {_, _, _, Except[1], _, _}, {2}] & // 
   DeleteCases[#, {_, Except[1 | 2], _, _, _, _}, {2}] &
  )
```

> {{{4, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1}}, {{3, 1,
> 1, 1, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1}}, {{4, 1, 3,     1, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 4, 1, 3, 1}}, {{1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2}}}

```
{Length /@ t, Times @@ Length /@ t}
```

> {{3, 3, 2, 1}, 18}

Hence the search has been cut down to 18 possibilities only.

```
pos = First@Position[Outer[Plus, Sequence @@ t, 1], sums]
res = Outer[List, Sequence @@ t, 1][[Sequence @@ pos]]
```

> {{4, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1}, {2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1}, {4, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 3,
> 1, 3, 2}}

```
MapThread[Position[#1, #2] &, {combs, res}] - 1 // Flatten
```

> {0, 2, 3, 4}